# Is it necessary to have a CSS selector of an ID within an ID?

Tags: html, css

For the purpose of this demo, I'll use a StackOverflow element for credibility.

If you sign out of SO, you can see a large call to action box at the top of the page. Even easier, just go to their new Portuguese version here - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Once you see the call to action box (captured below) go ahead and inspect it with developer tools.

[image]

On the div with the ID of `hero-content`, you will notice a style that I have pasted below:

```
#herobox #hero-content {
   background: #fff7d8;
   border: none;
}
```

I have done some research and as we all know, div ID's *should* be unique to the page. Although, if they are unique, why would a selector need to state an ID within an ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons.

Stylesheets can be reused between HTML documents. You may wish to distinguish between `#hero-content` that is a descendant of `#herobox` one page and of `#somethingelse` on another page.

The more likely one in this case is specificity. Assuming, for example, that `#hero-content` is a `<div>`, a general rule to set the styling of `#herobox div` would be more specific that `#herobox #hero-content`. Adding an extra id selector would increase the specificity.

Comment: Ahhh right, so it is basically being used to overwrite the already existing style on the `#hero-content` element.

Answer (score 2):

It might be simply to increase the specificity of that selector.

For example, the author may have wanted to override...

```
#hero-content { border: 2px solid #333; }
```

It could also be a side effect of a tool like LESS, where the author may have originally written...

```
#herobox {
    // Lots of other CSS.
    #hero-content {
        // ... 
    }
    // Lots of other CSS.
}
```

Comment: Never used LESS before, although it is becoming extremely popular, and it's no doubt that a huge site such as StackOverflow would use either LESS or SASS for useability. Thanks for your input Alex.